# Directly use of PostgreSQL's Multi-Version Concurrency Control

Tags: postgresql, mvcc

Is it possible to directly use  Multi-Version Concurrency Control  as client of  PostgreSQL database? I would like manually browse/add/delete/restore old versions.

My use case requires keeping multiple previous versions of the data (I have a lot  of data and a lot of versions).

In official documentation MVCC mechanism is described (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/mvcc-intro.html) but without any APIs to use it directly.

Comment: This might be more appropriate for the DBA Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put, no. MVCC isn't intended as a "version repository", and only keeps its "versions" of data long enough to satisfy the requirements of active transactions. Once a transaction concludes any data versions created to ensure data consistency for the transaction are discarded. The "multiple versions" of MVCC refer to differing versions or views of data which may be needed between different transactions. Within a single transaction only a single version of the data is ever visible. If you need to maintain "versions" of your data you'll need to make provisions for doing this yourself.

Best of luck.